# Post to facebook as branding page - PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I am having a fan page (or branding page) on Facebook. I have created a PHP application and I would like to post messages on this branding page, but NOT under my own user name, but as this brand name. So basically I would like to write in name of this brand, via PHP.

I have the following code:

```
    //This is the Page ID of the branding page
    $post_url = '/'.$userPageId.'/feed';

    // posts message on page feed
    $msg_body['message'] = $userMessage;

    if (!empty($userLink)) {
        $msg_body['link'] = $userLink;
    }
    if (!empty($userDescr)) {
        $msg_body['description'] = $userDescr;
    }
    if (!empty($userPic)) {
        $msg_body['picture'] = $userPic;
    }

  try {
        $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

The code places a message on the branding page, but from my own account. Any idea how I can write as if the message came from the brand itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you executing this script via a browser which has an open session to Facebook? Are you logged in as yourself?

Comment: Through the browser. I am logged in as myself. When I switch to this branding page, the PHP application asks me to switch to myself

Comment: Have you requested `manage_page` permission ?

Comment: Yes I have requested the manage_page permission: 
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,manage_pages';
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));

Comment: Update: The problem seems to be a link, photo or description. If I only post a message to Facebook, it is being placed as it came from the brand itself. The moment I add a link, it's being placed from my personal account... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it eventually. The problem was that I didn't pass the page access token. The following code works pretty well and also fixes the character encoding issue I had when posting extended ASCII signs:

```
$userPageId     = $_POST["userpages"];
$userMessage    = $_POST["message"];
$userLink   = $_POST["link"];
$userDescr  = $_POST["description"];
$userPic    = $_POST["picture"];
$access_token   = $_POST["page_access_token"];
$userCaption    = $_POST["caption"];

//HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/feed with the publish_stream
$post_url = '/'.$userPageId.'/feed';

// posts message on page feed
$userMessage = utf8_encode (stripslashes($userMessage)); 
$userMessage = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $userMessage);

$userCaption = utf8_encode (stripslashes($userCaption)); 
$userCaption = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $userCaption);

$userDescr = utf8_encode (stripslashes($userDescr)); 
$userDescr = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $userDescr);     

$msg_body['message'] = $userMessage;
$msg_body['access_token'] = $access_token;

if (!empty($userLink)) {
    $msg_body['link'] = $userLink;
}
if (!empty($userDescr)) {
    $msg_body['description'] = $userDescr;
}
if (!empty($userPic)) {
    $msg_body['picture'] = $userPic;
}
if (!empty($userCaption)) {
    $msg_body['caption'] = $userCaption;
}

if ($fbuser) {
  try {
    $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
  } 
      catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```